# High memory usage on iOS webkit using css 3 transforms

Tags: ios, css, safari

We're using css 3 transforms to build a UI that has elements that can be swiped and flipped. When we use these styles, and apply them to an element, we see high memory usage in safari mobile:

```
-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s;
transition: transform 0.5s;
-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
transform-style: preserve-3d;
-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.8s cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
transition: transform 0.8s cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
-webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
transform: rotateY(180deg);
```

Specifically, lots of extra graphics objects, CG raster data, are being created. We see this using instruments via xcode:

```
0   0x13087b000 VM: CG raster data  00:03.300.465   •   7.28 MB CoreGraphics    CGDataProviderCreateWithCopyOfData
```

When the element has none of these styles applied, this is the memory allocation profile:

```
0   0x12a6a5000 VM: CG raster data  00:03.290.109   •   7.28 MB CoreGraphics    CGDataProviderCreateWithCopyOfData
1   0x1239e9000 VM: CG raster data  00:03.289.774   •   1.65 MB CoreGraphics    CGDataProviderCreateWithCopyOfData
```

When the element has these styles applied we see this memory allocation profile:

```
0   0x13087b000 VM: CG raster data  00:03.300.465   •   7.28 MB CoreGraphics    CGDataProviderCreateWithCopyOfData
1   0x133c2f000 VM: CG raster data  00:03.306.677   •   6.32 MB CoreGraphics    CGDataProviderCreateWithCopyOfData
2   0x131bbe000 VM: CG raster data  00:03.302.266   •   6.32 MB CoreGraphics    CGDataProviderCreateWithCopyOfData
3   0x1335e3000 VM: CG raster data  00:03.305.898   •   6.30 MB CoreGraphics    CGDataProviderCreateWithCopyOfData
4   0x132fe1000 VM: CG raster data  00:03.304.956   •   6.01 MB CoreGraphics    CGDataProviderCreateWithCopyOfData
5   0x1315bc000 VM: CG raster data  00:03.301.709   •   6.01 MB CoreGraphics    CGDataProviderCreateWithCopyOfData
6   0x130fc2000 VM: CG raster data  00:03.301.151   •   5.98 MB CoreGraphics    CGDataProviderCreateWithCopyOfData
7   0x12d7ba000 VM: CG raster data  00:03.299.443   •   5.98 MB CoreGraphics    CGDataProviderCreateWithCopyOfData
8   0x132210000 VM: CG raster data  00:03.303.152   •   5.69 MB CoreGraphics    CGDataProviderCreateWithCopyOfData
9   0x12ddb4000 VM: CG raster data  00:03.299.949   •   5.68 MB CoreGraphics    CGDataProviderCreateWithCopyOfData
10  0x1327c1000 VM: CG raster data  00:03.304.192   •   5.40 MB CoreGraphics    CGDataProviderCreateWithCopyOfData
11  0x132d27000 VM: CG raster data  00:03.304.679   •   2.73 MB CoreGraphics    CGDataProviderCreateWithCopyOfData
12  0x12e363000 VM: CG raster data  00:03.302.855   •   2.58 MB CoreGraphics    CGDataProviderCreateWithCopyOfData
13  0x12d5e8000 VM: CG raster data  00:03.299.246   •   1.82 MB CoreGraphics    CGDataProviderCreateWithCopyOfData
14  0x1239e9000 VM: CG raster data  00:03.307.642   •   1.65 MB CoreGraphics    CGDataProviderCreateWithCopyOfData
```

It looks like safari mobile webkit is creating a graphics object for each of the transforms. The first and last core graphics object in both cases is the same.

We see this behaviour both on chrome and safari on iOS. We don't see this on desktop safari or chrome, we don't see this on android chrome.

Has anyone come across this, and does anyone know a way of remedying it that preserves the transforms?

edit:
we noticed this because we have elements set to opacity 0 but not hidden. We guess on android and desktop an optimisation has been done that removes the graphics objects when opacity is 0 but the same optimisation hasn't been applied on webkit on iOS.